# Finding the minimal value of a $4\times 4$ determinant

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, determinant, maxima-minima, diophantine-approximation

**The question.**

Let $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4)\in\mathbb R^4$ be a vector with irrational coordinates.

I am interested in finding the minimal value $\mu_\xi$ of

$$\left\vert \det \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & 0 & 1 \\ b_1 & b_2 & 1 & 0 \\ c_1 & c_2 & \xi_1 & \xi_3 \\ d_1 & d_2 & \xi_2 & \xi_4 \end{pmatrix} \right\vert,$$

for $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2\in\mathbb Z$, in terms of the area of the parallelepiped formed by the two vectors $X_i:=(a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i)$, $i=1,2$ (which I assume linearly independent), in $\mathbb R^4$.

Let's call this area $D(X_1,X_2)$. I know we have

$$\begin{align*} D(X_1,X_2)^2 &= \Vert X_1\Vert^2\Vert X_2\Vert^2-(X_1\cdot X_2)^2 \end{align*},$$

but I have no clue on how to proceed from here.

**The conjecture.**

My hope (which would help the construction of another proof a lot) would be that if we chose the $\xi_i$ properly, we can show that the minimal value verifies

\begin{equation}
\mu_\xi\geqslant \frac c{D(X_1,X_2)^2}\qquad\qquad (1)
\end{equation}

where $c$ is a constant (it may depends on $\xi$).

**Final remarks.**

Despite the fact that I strongly believe that $(1)$ is true, any proof that would show that

$$\mu_\xi\geqslant \frac c{D(X_1,X_2)^\gamma}$$

for a $\gamma<4$ would be of great interest.

Comment: By the definition of the determinant, your minimun depends well on $\xi$ vector. If you take the two vectors the area formula $D(X_1,X_2)$ isn't right if it is the triangle area formed by $X_1,X_2$.


So either you compute the expression and minimize if possible, either i guess taking particular values of $\xi$ and see a geometric proof.

Comment: @ToniMhax I edited to specify what I mean by the area formed by $X_1$ and $X_2$. Yes, the minimum depends on $\xi$, but I am interested in a particular value of $\xi$ that would solve the conjecture.

Comment: I think $D(X_1,X_2)^2=||X_1||^2||X_2||^2-(X_1•X_2)^2$

Comment: @Empy2 You're right, thank you, I edited.

Comment: In fact you go to the three dimension, instead take the triangle area rather than this, the volume (det) in $4$ dimension has $2$ dimensions depending on the two vectors $X_1,X_2$, the other two are  depending on $\xi$.

Comment: @ToniMhax Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean. $D(X_1,X_2)$ as I defined it is the area I am interested about.

Comment: It complicates the thing, the four vectors (columns) of the matrix have a volume in dimension $4$, you see $X_1,X_2$  are a two dimensional object, when you want $c$ depending on $\xi$ it would depend on $D(X_1,X_2)$ as you defined.

Comment: @ToniMhax Yes, but I am interested in the volume of the parallelepiped defined by $X_1,X_2$ view in the place $\text{Vect}(X_1,X_2)$ (which is two-dimensional). And I don't want the constant $c$ depending on $D(X_1,X_2)$, since all the information on $X_1$ and $X_2$ must be contained in the denominator of the fraction.

Comment: Ok for the minimum you need more constraints is it $X_1\neq X_2$ only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83682/discussion-between-toni-mhax-and-e-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wide so we need notations, 
for any $(X_1,X_2)$ in ${\mathbb{Z}}^2$ distinct, there is $A$
such that
$\dfrac{1}{D(X_1,X_2)}\le \dfrac{1}{A}$.  $C:=area(X_1,X_2)\ge a$ (parallelogram) also $a\neq 0$ exist.
The determinant is the volume of the four column vectors of the given matrix [which we suppose invertible] and equals $\mu_{\xi}=C.\alpha_{\xi}\ge \frac{c_{\xi}}{A}\ge \frac{c_{\xi}}{D(X_1,X_2)} $ for some $\alpha_{\xi}$ where $c_{\xi}= a.A.\alpha_{\xi}$.

Edit  $D(X_1,X_2)$ is the volume of $(X_1,X_2, X_1\times X_2)$

Finding the minimum value $a$  explicitly is the same as finding the minimum value of $A$.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I do not see how it is related to any kind of answer to this question...

Comment: It shows for any $\xi$ the existence of $c_{\xi}$ as in the bound.

Comment: But your $c_\xi$ depends on $X_1,X_2$, which is not allowed unfortunately.

Comment: Nop.   Anyway we hit a wall of supposing the matrix invertible.  
$a$ and $A$ can be computed, (hard now)  when the vectors $X_1,X_2$ are in ${\mathbb{Z}}^4$

Comment: I could not follow any of your computations. How can you get a sharp bound when your proof basically starts saying that $D(X_1,X_2)$ is non-zero?

Comment: I didn't as i said $a,A$ are finite fixed this is another problem, it should be known i guess.

Comment: $D(X_1,X_2)$ the parallelipiped volum isn't the one given, in fact the formula is the area of the parallelogram,  strange