# Finding a minima for a linear form with integer coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, diophantine-approximation, dual-spaces

**Some context.**

This question is aiming to fill gaps in a larger proof, so in a way, it is kind of related to this two other questions ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931552/finding-the-minimal-value-of-a-4-times-4-determinant) and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932799/a-linear-form-can-not-be-too-small-on-integer-points)) that I asked earlier. But since the problem is formulated in a different way, maybe it will be easier to solve it.

**The question.**

You can choose $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4)\in(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)^4$ however you want, you just need $\xi_5:=\xi_1\xi_4-\xi_2\xi_3\ne 0$.

Can we choose $\xi$ wisely so that there exists a constant $\gamma>0$ and a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\forall a=(a_1,\ldots,a_6)\in\mathbb Z^6\setminus\{0\},\quad \vert a_1\xi_1+a_2\xi_2+a_3\xi_3+a_4\xi_4+a_5\xi_5+a_6\vert\geqslant\frac c{\Vert a\Vert^\gamma}$$

where $\Vert a\Vert^2=a_1^2+\dots+a_6^2$.

**Remarks.**

The larger $\gamma$ we find, the weaker the result will be, but the easier it will be to prove. Ideally, I would love to find a $\gamma\in[2,4]$.

Anyway, any hint, lead or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried anything like $\xi_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mathrm{pow}(1/10, j^{\hspace{0.02cm}(i+1)})$ where pow$(x,n)= x^n$?

Comment: @irchans No I don't, I you know how to formalise your idea, feel free to post it has an answer :) (I'll try it too) (I think you meant $\xi_j$)

Comment: Correcting the formula for my suggested values of $\xi$ :  $\xi_i=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathrm{pow}(1/10, j^{\hspace{0.02cm}(i+1)})$ where pow$(x,n)= x^n$.  So $\xi_1=1+10^{-1}+10^{-4}+10^{-9}\ldots$, $\xi_2=1+10^{-1}+10^{-8}+10^{-27}\ldots$, $\xi_3=1+10^{-1}+10^{-16}+10^{-81}\ldots$, and $\xi_4=1+10^{-1}+10^{-32}+10^{-243}\ldots$.  I hesitate to post it as an "answer".  It is merely a starting point for a discussion.

Comment: @irchans Thanks for the clarification. I have looked at it, but I don't really know how I can use your $\xi_i$.

Comment: You may have a look at [Baker's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem). In general, your statement is wrong, just take $\xi_1 = - x_2$ and $\xi_3 = \xi_4$, then $\xi_5 \ne 0$, but for $a=(n,n,0,0,0,0)$ your some is zero. You will need linearly independence over $\mathbb{Q}$. Moreover, your statement is beyond current results in Diophantine Approximation. The constant in Baker's Theorem depends also on $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_4$ and is 'very large'.

Comment: @p4sch Thanks for the reference, it looks similar to my problem, I'll have a close look at it. However, like I said in the question, I am not interested in the question *for all* $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_4)$, but just for one $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_4)$ properly chosen.